# Is it possible to combine javascript files to avoid too many http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

I just need some help, am speed optimize a html website and the problem is that it has too many .js files around 23.

so is there any way to combine these js files so there will be less http requests,

i dont have any  access to the server side, so gzip is not possible

Comment: With server side you mean the location of JS files, not the location of your website, right?

Comment: google's closure compiler is one option : https://developers.google.com/closure/

Answer (score 2):

To speed optimize your site try to combine and minify your js files via this website http://jscompress.com/ (I advise you to keep a backup of course) Go to the tab upload javascript files and upload multimuple js files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You could modify your build definition in your code editor or use script loaders like "RequireJS" for ex..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can use tools like gulp with module `gulp-concat`

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

It will automatically refresh concated file after each change in these file. Moreover you will be able to minify the result file (by removing white chars).

If you are using some web CMS without FTP you can manually do the job using online combine tool like http://jscompress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Append all the JS files you're using on your server in the order they are loaded up in the HTML head, and then just load that one file. There are many ways/tools to do it. In the end, you should have a file that looks like this:

```
// 1st JS file code here

// 2nd JS file code here

// 3rd JS file code here

// etc
```

To speed things further, you can **minify** that combined JS file, and that's pretty much it.

You didn't specify the structure of your website, so I can't give you a more accurate answer in case things get more complex, but the bottom line is: **yes, it's possible (and recommended)**.